# Highstock Navigator Displayed Twice

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am using highstock,5.0.10 with **angularJS**.
In my chart navigator got displayed twice, like below

[image]

As you can see, navigator has been rendered twice. However, if you refresh the page, everything looks fine.
Any ideas?

I have added my Highstock code here.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('FindComputerUsage', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage of time (%) '
                }

            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {

                    var date = new Date(requiredData[this.points[0].point.index][0]);
                    return date + '<br>' + 'Percentage:' + requiredData[this.points[0].point.index][1] + '%';
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Percentage (%)',
                data: requiredData,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2,
                }
            }],
            lang :{
                noData : "No data to display "
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please can you provide some code? Your `Highcharts.stockChart`

Comment: Hi, thks. I have updated my question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/OphM9wf8WyGm8U6HXfTy

You haven't show your HTML view, but I guess it's similar to this.

```
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
</div>
```

Concerning controller scope, I didn't change anything:

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.data = [
                  [1290729600000,45.00],
                  [1290988800000,45.27],
                  [1291075200000,44.45]
                ];

  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Qing Xu Example'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Value',
            data: $scope.data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
  })

});
```